# Why does sizeof(A), for some array A, not work inside a function?

Tags: c++

The following

```
#include <iostream>

void printArraySize ( int * arr ) 
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

}

int main () 
{
    int arr [] = {1, 2, 3, 69203};
    printArraySize(arr);  
    return 0;
}
```

outputs `1` (Proof: http://codepad.org/yKG3mZIz). Explain this nonsense. Does an array forget its size once it enters a function? From what I understand, passing in `arr`, a memory address, a number, just means making a copy of that number. So `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)` should mean the same thing inside and outside of the function.

Comment: This is a very old and common question... Your function doesn't receive an array, but a pointer to `int`. In `main` you transmit `arr` which is declared as an array but converted to a pointer to the first element of it because you cannot have array passed to functions in C, only pointers.

Comment: Reopened and re-closed as duplicate, but now of the `sizeof` discussion in the SO C++ array FAQ (because the existing alleged duplicate was for the C langauge, and for this question the difference between C and C++ is very significant).

Comment: Your assertions in the question make no sense. Don't accuse the language of "nonsense" when you're making it yourself :P

Answer (score 2):

In `main`, `arr` is an array and `sizeof` yields the size of the array.

In `printArraySize`, `arr` is a pointer to `int` and `sizeof` yields the size of the pointer to `int` object.

In C you cannot pass (directly) arrays to functions, you can only pass a pointer to the first element of the array. To get the size of the array in `printArraySize` you need to pass it explicitly as an argument to the function.

In C++ you can pass C arrays by reference but you shouldn't use C arrays in the first place but use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: **–1** “You cannot pass (directly) arrays to functions, you can only pass a pointer to the first element of the array.” is true in C, but in C++ arrays can be passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you check `sizeof ( int*)` which is sizeof pointer to int. This is because arr passed to function in

```
int arr [] = {1, 2, 3, 69203};
printArraySize(arr);
```

decays to a pointer to int. It is just a pointer to integer, first element of array.

C

For doing what you would like to achieve there is a macro often used (for static arrays):

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof((x)) / sizeof((x)[0]))
```

example:

```
int arr [] = {1, 2, 3, 69203};
printf( "%d", ARRAY_SIZE(arr));
```

C++

```
template<class T, size_t n>
size_t array_size( T(&)[n]) {
    return n;
}
```

Comment: there is justice in this world

Comment: Not really. It's not Alf's job to "undo" someone else's right to vote. Sigh. "Justice" is about objective values but voting is a subjective act.

Comment: well, it is not coincidence that we think about democracy as most right and fair system, this works so good because we trust the correct choice can be made when pointed out by majority of votes. In other words the (incorrect) noise will be filtered out